# Group by in SQL returning error: Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group

Tags: sql, group-by, teradata

I have a table that looks like this:

```
       date      store   flag
1    5/4/2018      a       1
2    5/4/2018      a       1
3    5/3/2018      b       1
4    5/3/2018      b       0
5    5/2/2018      a       1
6    5/2/2018      b       0
```

I want to group by date and store and sum the number of flags

i.e. table_a below:

```
       date      store   total_flag
1    5/4/2018      a       2
3    5/3/2018      b       1
4    5/2/2018      a       1
5    5/2/2018      b       0
```

This is what I'm trying:

```
create multiset volatile table flag_summary as (
 sel table_a.*, SUM(table_a.flag) as total_flag
 group by date, store
)
with data primary index (date, store) on commit preserve rows;
```

The above gives me an error, "CREATE TABLE Failed. [3504] Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group.

Comment: There are additional column besides `date/store`, either add them to `group by` or apply an aggregate on them like `min(additionalcolumn)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting all of `tableA` (including the flag). You should just be pulling the date and the store since you want the sum of the flag.

```
SELECT date, store, SUM(flag)
FROM tableA
GROUP BY date, store
```